# wizard (or an alternative) in an aui managed pane

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, wizard

I would like to have wizard in my application. but I don't want the focus to be on the wizard until the wizard is finished. That's what happens if I use wx.wizard. I prefer to load the wizard in an aui pane. So the user can switch to main window even in the middle of the wizard. I can have panels on top of each to make a wizard. Kindly point me if there is a better Pythonic way of doing that.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wizard "widget" in wxPython is basically a dialog. I don't think you can embed it in your application. You might be able to extend the widget somehow to do so, but that would likely be a lot of work.

Instead, I would just create a set of panels that are your wizard pages. You will need a main panel that has some buttons on it that you place your pages on. Then when you hit the button, it will show the next page. I wrote a tutorial on the subject a couple years ago that should get you started:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/12/wxpython-how-to-create-a-generic-wizard/